# Named destinations in pdf - Chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I am attempting to open named destinations in pdfs in Chrome. This will be used in a tool that I am developing but I am testing it in more general Chrome first. Some of my destinations open up on the right page and right section, which I can see in Adobe Acrobat. However, some of them either open at the top or bottom of the page, instead of the correct section. Is there a way I can fix this? It works perfectly fine in Firefox so I am unsure why it does not work in Chrome.